# How to add a text prefix to an array on Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, text, map-function

Right now I have a array that when printed just displays what number I submitted. I would like the word `"car"` to be in front of every array number. For example: I enter 1 and 2 in the array. When the array is called it would look like `[car 1, car 2]` not `[1,2]`.

I have added my array variable and what I am calling to print the array:

```
var arrayOfInt = [Int]()
label.text = String(describing: arrayOfInt)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
let arrayOfInt: [Int] = [1, 2]
let cars = arrayOfInt.map { "car \($0)" }
```

as a result, the `cars` array will be:

```
["car 1", "car 2"]
```

finally, convert to string as before:

```
label.text = String(describing: cars)
```

The [`Array.map`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Array/#comment-func-map) function returns an array containing the results of *mapping* the given closure over the array's elements. In other words, it *tranforms* one array into another one by applying the specified function on each element.

Comment: A slight modification that avoids building the array:

        let numCars = 11
        let cars = Array(1...numCars).map { "car \($0)" }